# How to change page and go to top of the page when clicks on a link. ui-router angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Brand list rendering like this:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in Brands">
        <a ui-sref="Brand({ BrandID: x.id })">{{ x.name }}</a> </h4> 
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="sc in x.subcategories | orderBy:'scname' ">
                <td><a ui-sref="Brand({BrandID: x.id, scrollTo: sc.scid})">{{sc.scname}}</a> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and here is the logic to move to specific sub category of a brand.

```
sampleApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('Brand', {
        templateUrl: "templates/Products.html",
        url: '/Brand/:BrandID/:scrollTo',
        controller: 'ProductsController as pc',
        onEnter: function ($location, $stateParams, $anchorScroll, $timeout) {
            $timeout(function() { 
                $location.hash($stateParams.scrollTo);
                $anchorScroll()
            }, 100)
        }
    });
});
```

when user clicks this link (brand name with scid)

```
<a ui-sref="Brand({BrandID: x.id, scrollTo: sc.scid})">
```

I am able to go-to specific portion of the page.

But when user click on: (only brand name)

```
<a ui-sref="Brand({ BrandID: x.id })">{{ x.name }}</a> </h4>
```

I want to change page and go to top of the page. But change page is happening and its not going to top of page.

What changes needed to make it work?

Comment: have a hash on top of the page and provide it for brand without categories

Comment: Have u tried using scrollto like u did with the first one. But this time scrollto something at the top of you page.

Comment: can use `$stateChangeSuccess` event handler to adjust page scroll